# SKShapeNode position inconsistency after creation

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've been trying to draw lines and apply transformations to them using SpriteKit but I keep getting this inconsistency when I create a SKShapeNode at a certain position and try to read that position at a later time (including right after I create the node):

```
import SpriteKit


func buildLine(x0: CGFloat, y0: CGFloat, x1: CGFloat, y1: CGFloat) -> SKShapeNode {
    let line = SKShapeNode()
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x0, y: y0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x1, y: y1))
    line.path = path
    return line
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let line = buildLine(x0: -1, y0: -1, x1: 1, y1: 1)
        print(line.position) // expected (-1, -1), got (0, 0) instead
        addChild(line)
        print(line.position)  // expected (-1, -1) even more, got (0, 0) again
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // I've also tried accessing the position here (by creating the line at the class scope),
        // but still getting (0, 0) instead of (-1, -1)
    }
}
```

The anchor point is set to (0.5, 0.5). I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

think of `path.move(to:)` and `path.addLine(to:)` like you're moving the position of a virtual pencil. it's moving around to construct the path.

`line.position` will give you the underlying SKShapeNode's position, which in the above code you haven't altered. (following the pencil metaphor, the SKShapeNode would be more like the paper on which the path is drawn. drawing the points of the path is different from positioning the paper.)

Comment: Your analogy helped me clarify the underlying mechanism. I'll look for a way in which I can set the position explicitly.